# Destructure object parameter, but also have reference to the parameter as an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

With ES6 you can destructure objects in function arguments:

```
({name, value}) => { console.log(name, value) }
```

The equivalent ES5 would be:

```
function(params) { console.log(params.name, params.value) }
```

But what if I would like a reference both to the `params` object and the nested properties `value` and `name`? This is the closest I got, but the drawback is that it won't work with arrow functions because they do not have access to the `arguments` object:

```
function({name, value}) {
  const params = arguments[0]
  console.log(params, name, value)
}
```

Comment: `function(params){const {name,value}=params;console.log(params,name,value)}`?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman Yeah that comes very close. There's still an assignment line so I guess my question was: is it possible to do that in the function signature, like `function({name,value}=params) `

Comment: no, it only makes the core hard to read and confusing specially when you start using arrow functions. no real benefit to it.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I agree, was just curious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`arguments` isn't available in arrow functions, and this affects how function parameters should be consistently treated in ES6.

If original parameter is used, it should be destructured inside function:

```
(param) => {
  const {name, value} = param;
  // ...
}
```

If several arguments are expected and some argument negotiation takes place (for example, similarly to `arguments.length`), rest parameter should be used:

```
(...args) => {
  const [param] = args;
  // ...
}
```

Boilerplate variable destructuring has its benefits; it's easier this way to debug `param` or `args` at breakpoint even if they aren't currently in use.

Comment: Thanks, I think the answer gives a good summary of idiomatic use vs available options

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. I'm using this style myself as a rule of thumb, because param destructuring looks neat, but debugging was an issue for me numerous times in arrow callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

What about next:

```
function({name, value}, params=arguments[0]) {
    console.log(params, name, value)
}
```

Or:

```
function(params, {name, value} = params) {
    console.log(params, name, value)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work using arrow functions.

Comment: @Ele updated, must work now

Comment: I find this very confusing because it seems like the function expects 2 arguments. Furthermore it will work for a single parameter, but fails when you do `x({name: 'name', value: 'value'}, {name: 'name2', value: 'value2'})`