# Destruct object properties in array.map() and keep object as parameter

Tags: reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to destruct the properties of an object while keeping the object as a parameter inside an `array.map()` function?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075043/destructure-object-parameter-but-also-have-reference-to-the-parameter-as-an-obj) I tried the following but failed (parsing error)

```
  this.state.files.map(((file, {param1, param2} = file), i) => (
    <div key={i}>
      <p>{param1}</p>
      <button onClick={this.editFile(file)} />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to use the [default parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), like so:

```js
const test = (input, { a, b } = input) => [ a, b ]
console.log(test({ a: 1, b: 2 })) // [ 1, 2 ]
```

No second parameter is passed to the function above, so the second parameter defaults to the first parameter, then it is destructed.

The parameter can only be used after it has been declared, so this won't work:

```js
const test = ({ a, b } = input, input) => [ a, b ]
console.log(test(undefined, { a: 1, b: 2 }))
// Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined at test
```

This can also only work if no parameter is passed, so in the case of a callback being passed to `Array#map`, you must declare all of the parameters being passed so that you can declare the default parameter.

With your example it would look like this:

```js
this.state.files.map((file, i, files, { param1, param2 } = file) => (
  <div key={i}>
    <p>{param1}</p>
    <button onClick={this.editFile(file)} />
  </div>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using lambda component make it a functional block like so

```
  this.state.files.map(((file, i) => {
    const {param1, param2} = file;
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <p>{param1}</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.editFile(file)} />
      </div>
    )}
  )
```